# Add a column to heroku postgres database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

So, locally I've changed my models a few times and used South to get everything working.  I have a postgres database to power my live site, and one model keeps triggering a column `mainsite_message.spam does not exist` error.  But when I run `heroku run python manage.py migrate mainsite` from the terminal, I get `Nothing to migrate`.  All my migrations have been pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the list of migrations available for your apps (it will mark what are pending and what others are migrated).

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate <your app name> --list
```

if you have migrated with --fake, then identify the number of migration is pending (0003, for example) then do a revert of migrations to get the the previous state:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate <your_app_name> 0002 --fake
```

now try again to migrate.

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate <your app name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run schemamigration before? If yes, go to your database and take a look at your table  "south_migrationhistory" there you can see what happened.

If you already did the steps above you should try to open your migration file and take a look as well, there you can find if the creation column is specified or not!

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you have created a migration to add mainsite_message.spam to the schema. Have you made sure that this migration is in your git repository?

If you type `git status` you should see untracked files. If the migration is untracked you need to `git add path_to_migration` and then push it to Heroku before you can run it there.

Comment: No, it's definitely been added.  I did some finagling with --fake; maybe I skipped it somehow and need to backtrack?